# Pipfileのサンプルコードに記載されている`"e1839a8"`は、どんな意味でしょうか？

Tags: python, pipenv

Pipenvの公式サイトのサンプルコードには、以下のように記載されています。

```
$ pipenv install --dev -e .

$ cat Pipfile
...
[dev-packages]
"e1839a8" = {path = ".", editable = true}
...
```

https://pipenv-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/basics.html#editable-dependencies-e-g-e

`"e1839a8" = {path = ".", editable = true}`の`e1839a8`は、どんな意味でしょうか？
たぶんハッシュ値だと思うのですが、なぜ自分自身のパッケージ名ではないのでしょうか？

requestsモジュールのPipfileにも同様の記述があったので、疑問に思いました。
https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/Pipfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

同様の話題が`pipenv`のGithubのIssueに上がっていたので翻訳を載せておきます。

> Pipenv is not smart enough to provide a better key (it really is not possible), so it just uses a hash to act as placeholder. It can be anything, so you are free to change the key to anything you want (as long as it does not duplicate other keys, of course).

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1744#issuecomment-373432495

Pipenvはもっと良い key を提供できるほど賢くありません。(本当に無理)
だからプレースホルダーとしてハッシュ値を使っていますが好きな値に変えてしまって構いません。(もちろん重複しない限りに置いてですが)